# A batch file that run a program on a specific date and time and year

Tags: batch-file, timer

At our school, we prevent users from using notepad. But we would like to create a batch file, that we will install in start up to run notepad.exe on a specific date and time, each month. It may be each 5th January and each 5th February 2016. The batch file, once run, may execute the notepad.exe on each 5th January. We have tried with code below, but it's not working. We need some help please.

```
@echo off
:finddate
if %date% GEQ 29/12/2015 goto start
goto finddate

:start
start Notepad.exe
goto end
:end
```

Comment: Does it have to be a batch file? Are you open to other suggestions?

Comment: Why are you not trying to do this with a scheduled task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use vbscript?

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Dim dt
dt=now
if (day(dt) = 5 and month(dt) = 1) Then
    objShell.Run(chr(34)&"C:\Program Files\Notepad.exe"&chr(34))
End If
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, but if i want it to execute the .exe situated in a specific path, how can i do it?? for example execute notepad.exe situated in C:\Program Files\Notepad.exe

Comment: do this: objShell.Run(chr(34)&"C:\Program Files\Notepad.exe"&chr(34))

Answer (score 2):

The best way to this might be to create the batch file, then schedule a task(s) Task Scheduler to run the file on specified date/time or whatever parameters you may need.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do this by using a scheduled task. Here is how you do this:

1. Open Task Scheduler and select "Action -> Create Basic Task" from the menu
2. During task creation select monthly trigger and select all months you want the task to be executed. For days, select "5".
3. For "Action" select "Start a Program" and browse for location of `notepad.exe` and select any optional arguments (if you maybe want to open a specific file in notepad)

Hope this helps!